# SQL filter more than 1 table in Cartodb.js

Tags: carto

I have a button on my map where when user clicks, it will filter 1 cartodb layer with SQL. I want to allow each button click to filter two layers, each sharing the same field and value. [Here is the working map](http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/Cartodb/LosAngeles.html#)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
    <nav>
<div id="layer_selector" class="menu-item">
<h4><a href="#">Supervisor Districts</a></h4>
<ul>
<li data="all" class="selected">All Districts</li>
<li data="1">District 1</li>
<li data="2">District 2</li>
<li data="3">District 3</li>
<li data="4">District 4</li>
<li data="5">District 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
    </nav>
<!-- include cartodb.js library -->
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/cartodb.js"></script>
<script>
// create layer selector
function createSelector(layer) {
var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'pledgemap' });
var $options = $('#layer_selector li');
$options.click(function(e) {
// get the area of the selected layer
var $li = $(e.target);
var area = $li.attr('data');
// deselect all and select the clicked one
$options.removeClass('selected');
$li.addClass('selected');
// create query based on data from the layer
var query = "select * from sup_dist_2011";
if(area !== 'all') {
query = "select * from sup_dist_2011 where sup_dist_n  = " + area;  
}

// change the query in the layer to update the map
layer.setQuery(query);
});
} 

function main() {
cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://pledgemap.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/c812bb36-b71d-11e4-b921-0e4fddd5de28/viz.json', {
tiles_loader: true,
center_lat: 34.15,
center_lon: -118,
zoom: 10
})

.done(function(vis, layers) {
// layer 0 is the base layer, layer 1 is cartodb layer
createSelector(layers[1])
})
.error(function(err) {
console.log(err);
});
}
window.onload = main;
</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple layers and you're pulling the data using a viz.json file, then the structure of the `layer` callback object is: `layer[0]` is the basemap, `layer[1]` are the static layers. There are one to many sublayers in `layers[1]`. If you are using createLayer, then the layer object consists of the multiple sublayers.

If you're [pulling the data from a viz.json file](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#create-a-visualization-from-scratch), your situation is probably like this:

```
cartodb.createVis('map','vizjson_link')
    .done(function(vis,layers) {
    var sublayer0 = layers[1].getSubLayer(0);
    var sublayer1 = layers[1].getSubLayer(1);

    $("#change-sublayer0").on('click',function(e) {
        sublayer0.setSQL(sql_string0);
    });

    $("#change-sublayer1").on('click',function(e) {
        sublayer1.setSQL(sql_string1);
    });

});
```

We also tried to address this in a Map Academy lesson on CartoDB.js: http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up/lesson-3.html

**Edit:**
There are three sublayers in `layers[1]`. Therefore, when you call `createSelector(layers[1])`, you can extract these sublayers like above within createSelector:

```
var sublayerSup = layer.getSubLayer(0);
var sublayerPledge = layer.getSubLayer(1);
```

You can then change the query applied to each of these in the `if` statement you set up:

```
var querySup = "SELECT * FROM sup_dist_2011";
var queryPledge = "SELECT * FROM pledge";

if(area !== 'all') {
  querySup = querySup + " where sup_dist_n  = " + area;
  queryPledge = queryPledge + " WHERE pledge = " + otherAttribute;
}

// change the query in the layer to update the map
sublayerSup.setSQL(querySup);
sublayerPledge.setSQL(queryPledge);
```

You should probably also add another data attribute to your list elements so that you can pull additional information from them:

```
<li data="all" class="selected">All Districts</li>
<li data="1" data-pledge="blah1">District 1</li>
<li data="2" data-pledge="blah2">District 2</li>
<li data="3" data-pledge="blah3">District 3</li>
<li data="4" data-pledge="blah4">District 4</li>
<li data="5" data-pledge="blah5">District 5</li>
```

Again within `createSelector` you can extract this data like this:

```
var pledge = $li.data('pledge');
```

By the way, you don't need to use the `var sql = new cartodb.SQL(...)` line because you're only interacting with sublayers, not the SQL component of CartoDB.js.

A little ramble-y, but hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for that. I updated my question and code. I am very novice at javascript and cartodb. Not sure where in the code to allow sublayer queries.

Comment: ok, updated answer to reflect new info.